# Unable to access docker container app from any port(using publish) other than default port of container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, containers

I am learning Docker. I have installed Docker for Windows. I have created the container for nginx and am trying to access the container using the published port but I am unable to access the same. However, if I use port 80 then I am able to access the application.

http://localhost:80 works and shows me the default nginx page
http://localhost:5000  doesnt works  and prints following:

```
This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Also, the network tab in browser (Chrome) developer console doesnt show any response or error

My OS: Windows 10 Pro

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.7
 Version:           20.10.2
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        2291f61
 Built:             Mon Dec 28 16:14:16 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.2
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       8891c58
  Built:            Mon Dec 28 16:15:28 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Command used for creating container:  `docker container run -d --name nginx --publish 5000:5000 nginx`

docker container ls output

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                            NAMES
f59516a3e4f7   nginx                    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 hours ago      Up 4 hours      80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   nginx
```

docker container inspect command:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "f59516a3e4f75c61b92479f965043e90a711fb193e443b734e05bcd42ad4d0ba",
        "Created": "2021-02-08T07:19:20.2360384Z",
        "Path": "/docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "nginx",
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 983,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-02-08T07:19:24.5867104Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:f6d0b4767a6c466c178bf718f99bea0d3742b26679081e52dbf8e0c7c4c42d74",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f59516a3e4f75c61b92479f965043e90a711fb193e443b734e05bcd42ad4d0ba/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f59516a3e4f75c61b92479f965043e90a711fb193e443b734e05bcd42ad4d0ba/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f59516a3e4f75c61b92479f965043e90a711fb193e443b734e05bcd42ad4d0ba/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f59516a3e4f75c61b92479f965043e90a711fb193e443b734e05bcd42ad4d0ba/f59516a3e4f75c61b92479f965043e90a711fb193e443b734e05bcd42ad4d0ba-json.log",
        "Name": "/nginx",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                49,
                190
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a67b581e2118bfaeb9a069c638ff42f71acf47fd265b01354e220c483ff9cf71-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/61d9567cb18bc9696a1c664ebf3825a418a9aff6c5aa2c0fabc953123431fa34/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2be9c39bd291d94c4c1d5988983962b9962c9b20cf1fa234ab03207cdad4fff8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/24572164f0e4eee1986a390325efa605d0479adf33dd98fee68664c36e6367c7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/874dc0dce371b28125310174ec54ae62cfce0d19966182d80ad614f160107c7a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/65ff43934235a5e51dd723ee580dfb1aaa83bf78f20e841593e75cb24018b3da/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a67b581e2118bfaeb9a069c638ff42f71acf47fd265b01354e220c483ff9cf71/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a67b581e2118bfaeb9a069c638ff42f71acf47fd265b01354e220c483ff9cf71/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a67b581e2118bfaeb9a069c638ff42f71acf47fd265b01354e220c483ff9cf71/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "f59516a3e4f7",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5000/tcp": {},
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.19.6",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.5.0",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1~buster"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "Image": "nginx",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers \u003cdocker-maint@nginx.com\u003e"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGQUIT"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "626e30b7e55d09190c8d1856ee22a5631cccd77b11dfc7833f790d657ff34a49",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/626e30b7e55d",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "e5b1acbe55d056354dcd377ea42c33a4acc37229af589da9fbf0ba70e812b3ea",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "eab20a894f1a3dfef855ac020cb83389f7e1b2b77b0ba25a3268db90c55a5a30",
                    "EndpointID": "e5b1acbe55d056354dcd377ea42c33a4acc37229af589da9fbf0ba70e812b3ea",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Output of nestat -ao in windows just to see if ports are not available

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             DESKTOP-FUFQTFP:0      LISTENING       9276
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            DESKTOP-FUFQTFP:0      LISTENING       616
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            DESKTOP-FUFQTFP:0      LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2179           DESKTOP-FUFQTFP:0      LISTENING       2196
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           DESKTOP-FUFQTFP:0      LISTENING       9276
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4000           DESKTOP-FUFQTFP:0      LISTENING       9276
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           DESKTOP-FUFQTFP:0      LISTENING       9276
```

DESKTOP-FUFQTFP is something I can see in Hyper V-Manager

I have gone through several posts and tried commands like `docker container run -d --name nginx -p 0.0.0.0:5000:5000 nginx`
but it didnt work
I also tried the same for images of httpd and docker/getting-started image but all are having the same issue.
I am clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue with command in your example is that you're mapping local port 5000 to port 5000 in container (nothing listening on it).

Thy this: `docker container run -d --name nginx --publish 5000:80 nginx`

Here port 5000 on your host is getting mapped (bound) to port 80 in the container.

Comment: The only difference between your command and mine is the use of container port 5000 in my case and 80 in yours. Are you suggesting that this might be happening because container port 5000 might not be available ? But, in that case docker wont start the container itself isnt it ?
I tried your command as well and result is same, unable to access.

Comment: Default NGINX container isn't exposing `:5000`. What would it need it for? Here's the [Dockerfile for current latest NGINX version from Docker Hub](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/41156d8a36bd03b2fb36353ba31f16ada08d9e48/mainline/debian/Dockerfile#L111). See line 111, only `:80` exposed by default - as you'd expect. Command in answer tested and works.

Comment: ok so you mean that the container port mentioned in the run command should essentially be same as what is mentioned as Expose  the DockerFile of the image ?
I have cleared all the images and tried and it worked !! Thanks! :)

Comment: Services in container can bind (listen) on different ports, multiple ones at the same time too. And you can expose them dynamically with your `-p <some-host-port>:<some-container-port>` (can be repeated more than once), not necessarily mapping to what's already exposed by Dockerfile. But in case of default NGINX container, there's just nothing listening on `:5000` inside it when you start it up, you need to map to `:80` to get the welcome page.